# Redispatching normalized mouse scroll events

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, qooxdoo

I'm a flex dev, and I need to make the scrolling experience in my flex app more uniform across browsers. Flex scrolling relies on the delta property of mouse scroll events, which we all know is different across browsers.

After reading another StackOverflow post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527601/normalizing-mousewheel-speed-across-browsers) I thought maybe I could somehow take advantage of the fact that qooxdoo has invested time in their MouseScroll event class with some crazy algorithm (http://news.qooxdoo.org/the-week-in-qooxdoo-2010-10-08).

So I wanted to redispatch this a new MouseSCroll event with the qooxdoo "normalized" delta property to flex.

Is this possible? I am rubbish at javascript so wouldn't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

As qooxdoo is open source, you can use the code / algorithm which can be found on github [1]. The class itself can not be used without parts of qooxdoo basic infrastructure so copying the algorithm would be the better option.

[1] https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/event/type/MouseWheel.js#L63