# Getting rid of CSS font-size padding without slowing Firefox scroll speed

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a web app where I have a lot of tall images that I want to display horizontally centered on the page inside a scrolling div with no padding on top or bottom whatsoever, with the whole thing wrapped in a "window" like in the [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/7wubgLb5/2/). Now, the problem here is that if you remove the `font-size: 0` declaration from the `.view`, you get a tiny amount of padding underneath the image. Setting the font size to 0 gets rid of that padding, but at the same time, it makes the scrolling inside the div really slow in Firefox because the scroll speed in Firefox is tied to `font-size`, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110224/what-is-the-height-of-a-line-in-a-wheel-event-deltamode-dom-delta-line). My question is - is there a way in this scenario to get rid of that annoying bit of extra padding without also crippling the Firefox scroll speed in the process?

I would like to avoid any kind of solutions that would rely on hardcoded values, eg. I *don't* want to do something like `img { margin-bottom: <-Xpx/-Xem>; }`, as this is not reliable cross-browser (for example, setting a 16px font size results in the extra padding being 3px in Chrome, 4px in Firefox and 5px in IE11).

HTML:

```
<div class="window">
    <div class="view">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/2000" alt="kitty" />
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with my own JSFiddle I managed to figure this one out on my own - I simply needed to wrap the image in an extra div and move the `font-size: 0` declaration inside it, and as a result the scroll speed remains sane in the actually scrolling parent div. Seems like posting about this ended up being a successful case of rubber duck debugging.

HTML:

```
<div class="window">
    <div class="view">
        <div class="wrap">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/2000" alt="kitty" />
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap { font-size: 0; }
```