# How to determine how much user will scroll by pixels when user start scrolling using mouse wheel in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, angular

How to determine what amount of pixels will be moved by vertical scroll bar when user start to scroll using mouse wheel in javascript

I have a situation where user's scroll will result change in offsetTop between 200px to 1000px that I like to know ahead of time, do we have any way to figure out this situation using javascript?

Comment: what have you tried for this?

Comment: @SandrinJoy I tried to get information how much page will be scrolled by first time executing the event handler(by wheel move event) and measuring the change in offsetTop value difference when scroll event ends, but I want it from the start, like before scroll event execution completes.

Comment: can you share that code?

Comment: please describe your question properly and show some code what you have tried

Comment: @SandrinJoy Please check https://jsfiddle.net/dipparmar/wgjmev17/43/

Comment: as far as I know this cannot be done, in fact the settings that say how much you will scroll down are contained in the mouse. which is why this may vary depending on the model and its settings.

Comment: @DipParmar your question is not clear.  as far as i understood , the scroll bar remaining portion & mouse wheel movement all depends on the system , hardware and the browser.

Comment: @Sandrin Joy I require position in pixels where scrollbar is going to stop after one mouse wheel event

Comment: @SandrinJoy and Giuppox Thanks for your views but is there any way with any property/method from browser we can get any value that can help us to get the end position by any additional calculation

Comment: u just want to find height of the body?

Comment: No, not height of doc or body, suppose your doc height is 500 and and your current offsetTop is 0. Now if you scroll once and your offetTop will change to around 100px so I want to get exact point where it will stop from start

Comment: its just doc height - screen size

Comment: No, you are saying about height of document, I am saying about end point of first scroll(first wheel movment), which we want to get from the start of the scrolling

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Magic-Crystal-Ball-See-Future/dp/076246514X

Comment: @DipParmar offsetTop is a read only property it cannot be altered you have to change the top of the element by using element.style.top

Comment: @Ac_mmi please read the question carefully, I don't want to change offsetTop Property

Comment: @DipParmar What  you meant by 'I have a situation where user's scroll will result change in offsetTop between 200px to 1000px'.

Comment: I just given an use case @Ac_mmi https://jsfiddle.net/dipparmar/jsgbpeqy/12/ please check this link here for that line, What I require is when you start to scroll, how much pixel browser will move for just one wheel movement, so simply just distance from start to stop but I require it before scroll ends.

Comment: @DipParmar You can use Delta.Y to check how much mouse wheel scrolled but won't provide you accurate value in px it would just show whether it is scrolled up or down.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem with DeltaY which I checked, it's value is different on different browser and OS and even what value we are getting those are not in pixels as well

Comment: Maybe if you share the why you want that information, we might be able to help.

Comment: @DipParmar This might work i just edited my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110224/what-is-the-height-of-a-line-in-a-wheel-event-deltamode-dom-delta-line this is what you were looking for ig

Comment: @Joshua I am trying to make footer fixed which is inside iframe but it should be adjusting it's position based on parent window scroll.. I am having lag in updating it's position while user scrolls so If I can get end position of scroll from start then I can animate it properly using animation property Note: can't use css fixed property as it will work only in view port so it will not work in my case

Comment: @DipParmar Why aren't you using `position: sticky;`, with `bottom: 0;`?

Comment: @Joshua with position property it will not work as our scroll is outside viewport and position property don't adjust it's position if any change occur in scroll position outside viewport, it's not that straight forward

Comment: @DipParmar i tried scrolling effect of  div block which will start scrolling at certain point and after reaching the end of it resume scrolling with respect to viewport Will this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the short answer is 'no'. To illustrate this, consider the following equivalent question:

> I have detected a `keydown` event on the `down` arrow. Can I predict when the user will release the `down` key?

This is not possible. It is up to the user when they release the key and you have no way of anticipating when this will be.

Regarding mouse wheel events specifically, you'd also need to consider hardware / mouse and software / browser variations, which is going to make an (already impossible?) task even more difficult.

**An alternative approach: Debounce your mouse-wheel events**

Without more information about your overall objective it is difficult to know whether this will help, but you can use a debounce function to normalise a mouse-wheel event across a period of time. So whether the user scrolls for (say) 0.5s or 1s, you will only get one event, which should simplify any calculations you need to do.

[Here is a basic Javascript Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-eyheaf), debouncing a mousewheel event to every 0.1s. If you do a continuous mouse-wheel scroll, only the first event should be emitted.

[RxJS has a `debounceTime` function](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) built in. I'm not familiar with React so I can't advise exactly how this would be applied to mouse events, but the principle would be the same as the example above.

Comment: I understand your point but suppose user scroll mouse wheel one time only then is there any way to get that value, like as you mentioned about key press suppose user only press key(down arrow) once then can we get the value in pixels where scrollbar will stop from the start(before scroll process internally ends in browser)

Comment: In theory, possibly, I guess, if you could get the vertical position of the screen before and after 'one' mouse-wheel event, you could subtract one from the other, but you can't going to know this until the mouse-wheel is used.

Practically speaking, I think even if you can get a value it's going to be very unreliable, because of the variations in hardware, software and user behaviour I've mentioned.

I think you'd be better off considering other solutions.

Comment: yeah that I already tried but it doesn't seem feasible as it will require at least one time that event to be occurred

Answer (score 0):

> I understood that you wanted to get the pixels are going to be scrolled when a scroll event starts.

### But this is not a just a web/code issue. The scroll keeps on ongoing until the user feels to stop.

*This also depends on the **mouse Wheel hardware** . There are mouses with hard wheels which stop exactly when we release our fingers & other mouses which having soft gears, continues the scroll motion a bit longer (Newton's Law of Motion).*

> Web developers has no control over these hardwares upcoming
> performances(predictive performances) such as when will the user
> release his finger from a particular key or when will the user release
> the mouse button etc...

**Only thing which we get is the hardware's completed/ongoing performances(Finished tasks/current) such as keyup , keydown,click , scrolling**

*These events returns what is happening as of now & what happened just before*

---

**Only way to predict what could be the expecting scroll duration  is by Machine Learning ,by understanding how usually the user scrolls , understanding about the scrolling device they use etc..**

*But why do we need it? The use case which i could come up with this is a ML model for understanding user's scroll behaviour*

> I have a situation where user's scroll will result change in offsetTop
> between 200px to 1000px that I like to know ahead of time, do we have
> any way to figure out this situation using javascript?

**For this particular scenario , there is no use case of getting the scrolling pixels before it stops.A basic scrolled event is more than enough.**

*Maybe you want this to give a mini animation before reaching 1000px , which can be done directly using css & javascript by creating a eventlistener on scroll (if current offsetTop==1000px then .... )*

*This is a snippet , which tells you how much pixel the user have scrolled in a scroll event(Completed task)*

```js
const ph=document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
console.log(ph)
document.querySelector('.rem').innerHTML="you have scrolled "+window.pageYOffset+". Scroll ends after "+((ph-window.innerHeight)-window.pageYOffset);
document.onscroll = () =>{
if(window.pageYOffset>1000){
 var cl=document.getElementById("gm");
 cl.classList.add("wow");
}
if(window.pageYOffset<1000){
 var cl=document.getElementById("gm");
 cl.classList.remove("wow");
}
document.querySelector('.rem').innerHTML="you have scrolled "+window.pageYOffset+". Scroll ends after "+((ph-window.innerHeight)-window.pageYOffset);
};
```

```css
.rem{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
.demo{
height:5000px;
}

.wow{
background:#FFCB2B;
transition:2s;
}
```

```html
<span class="rem" id="xy"></span>
<div class="demo" id="gm">
<div>
```

**Well yes , i will create a simple machine learning JS snippet for this scrolling event by first studying the user's scrolling behaviour**

*I am only training for a unidirectional scroll as of now.So for each scroll ,do either upscroll or downscroll*

*First 10 scrolls , will be only for Learning . Later onwards , when you start a scroll event , it will predict the upcoming scroll value with the learned values*

*The model will be learning continuously , as it won't stop after learning for first 10 tries. Higher the the learn value , more realistic prediction value u get*

```js
const ph=document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
const sp=[];
var prevscroll=0;
var curscroll=0;
learn=0;
var scrollTimer = -1;
console.log(ph)
document.querySelector('.rem').innerHTML="you have scrolled "+window.pageYOffset+". Scroll ends after "+((ph-window.innerHeight)-window.pageYOffset);

document.onscroll = () =>{

if (scrollTimer != -1)
       clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
  scrollTimer = window.setTimeout("scrollFinished()", 300);
if(learn>=10){
var c=avgscroll()
document.querySelector('.rem').innerHTML="your expected scroll pixels are "+c;
}

};
function avgscroll(){
  curavg=0
sp.forEach((item, index)=>{
      if(index!=0)
        curavg=(curavg+item)/(2)
       else
          curavg=item
});
return curavg;
}
function scrollFinished() {
        learn=learn+1;
        curpoint=window.pageYOffset
        curscroll=Math.abs(window.pageYOffset-prevscroll);
        prevscroll=curpoint;
        sp[learn]=curscroll
        console.log("Current Scroll was "+ curscroll)
        if(learn<=10)
        document.querySelector('.rem').innerHTML="Current Scrolled pixels were "+curscroll+" learning "+ learn + " of 10";
        
    }
```

```css
.rem{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
.demo{
height:50000px;
}
```

```html
<span class="rem" id="xy"></span>
<div class="demo">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dip Parmar, I'm giving you both, the previous scroll position and the current scroll position in a separate useDocumentScroll.js file. Previous scroll is the end point of one scroll which ur looking for. I have done it in React functional hooks. You can make use of them accordingly as required in the RequiredPage.js by putting your own logic. I have also included some logic..  isScrolledDown & isMinimumScrolled for you. I could not exactly get what you wanted to make using it. My code for ur question is as below:

useDocumentScroll.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function useDocumentScroll(callback) {
  const [, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  let previousScrollTop = 0;

  function handleDocumentScroll() {
    const { scrollTop: currentScrollTop } =
      document.documentElement || document.body;

    setScrollPosition(previousPosition => {
      previousScrollTop = previousPosition;
      return currentScrollTop;
    });

    callback({ previousScrollTop, currentScrollTop });
  }

   useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleDocumentScroll);

    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleDocumentScroll);// eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
}

export default useDocumentScroll;
```

RequiredPage.js

```
import React from "react";    
import useDocumentScroll from "./useDocumentScroll";

export default function RequiredPage() {
const MINIMUM_SCROLL = 80;

useDocumentScroll(callbackData => {
const { previousScrollTop, currentScrollTop } = callbackData;
const isScrolledDown = previousScrollTop < currentScrollTop;
const isMinimumScrolled = currentScrollTop > MINIMUM_SCROLL;
});

return (
     <div>
     <h1>Some Text or Add some Lorem Ipsum </h1>
     </div>
       );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment **'I am trying to make footer fixed which is inside iframe but it should be adjusting it's position based on parent window scroll..'** based on what you said i tried to make something which will suit your requirement.

#### See this in fullscreen

```js
var block=document.getElementById('div');
    
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
var scrolled=window.scrollY;
   
if(scrolled>=471 && scrolled<=963){
    block.style.overflowY="scroll";
    
    
    if(block.scrollTop>=519){
        block.style.overflowY="hidden";
    
    }
    else if(block.scrollTop>=0){
        
    block.scrollTop+=(scrolled-519);
    window.scrollTo(0,scrolled);
    
}


}
else{
    if(scrolled<=741){
    block.style.overflowY="scroll";
   
    block.scrollTop=0;
    if(block.scrollTop<=0){
        block.style.overflowY="hidden";
    }
}

    window.scrollTo(0,scrolled);
}
});
```

```css
*{
            margin: 0px;
            padding:0px;
        
        }
        body{
            height:2400px;
        }
        p{
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #div{
           position: absolute;
           scroll-behavior: smooth;
           height:401px; 
           width: 97vw;
           margin-top:570px;
           background-color:black;
           color: white; 
           padding:10px;
           z-index: 14;
        }
        #div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
        #p_3{
            position: absolute;
            margin-top:940px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            z-index: 11;
            width: 100vw;
            padding: 10px;
            
        }
        #p_1{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            z-index: 11;
            width: 100vw;
            padding: 10px;
            
        }
```

```html
<div id="p_1">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="div">
    <div id="p">
    <p >1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color:red; color:white">2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color: #FF5733; color:white">3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color:#FCB607; color:white">4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color:#FCDB07 ; color:white">5 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color: yellow; color:white">6 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color: #07D7FC; color:white">7 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color: #07B2FC; color:white">8 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color: #0755FC; color:white">9 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p style="background-color: black; color:white">10 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="p_3">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

### But if you still want to stick to mouseWheel then you should go after IntersectionObserver.

#### The “Intersection Observer” provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection (overlapping) of elements. This can be in relation to other elements, or the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

What i guess from your query you want this kind of solution

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    let scroll = this.scrollY;
    console.log(scroll)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height:900px;background-color:limegreen;">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I want to get information about end position in pixels on first time handler execution. (just for one time mouse wheel movement)

Comment: "How to determine how much user will scroll by pixels when user start scrolling using mouse wheel in JavaScript" this was your query which means continuity that's what i get

Comment: That's why I mentioned How much it will move but not it already moved

Comment: man question itself saying for future position not for position already where we are