# Mousewheel delaying/delta summing function extremely jolty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page with multiple full screen panels. For ascetic purposes, I am trying to make the user have to scroll a certain amount of wheel deltas for the body to animate to the next page. I have no idea what I am doing wrong over here:

```
page = document.body.scrollTop;
currentPage = 0;
tick = 0;
wheelBounds = 500;
wheelTimeout = null;

window.onmousewheel = function(e){
    clearTimeout(wheelTimeout);
    document.body.scrollTop = page;
    tick += -e.wheelDelta;
    wheelTimeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        tick = 0;
    },100);
    // document.body.scrollTop = window.innerHeight*(currentPage);
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: window.innerHeight*(currentPage)
    });
    if(tick > wheelBounds || tick <-wheelBounds){
        page = document.body.scrollTop;
        currentPage = tick > wheelBounds ? (currentPage+1): currentPage > 0 ?(currentPage-1): currentPage;
        tick = 0;
        console.log(currentPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you better explain what is going wrong?  Also, what browser are you doing this in?  Wheel deltas can differ between browsers.  [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5527601/691711)

Comment: it keeps jolting back extremely rapidly between the first and second page on scroll. this is in chrome