# Detect the number of times mouse wheel was spun and not the length it was spun

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a div scroll for the number of times the wheel spins rather than the length the wheel was spun. Is this possible?

E.g. If the user spin the mouse wheel x length I need to pass a value as 10. Also if a user spin the mouse wheel x/4 length I still need to pass the value 10.

example::  something like this - Each time it spins increase the value by 1 only.

```
var i = 0;
$("#divD").on('scroll', function() {
  i++;
});
```

Comment: It may not be possible, but [here is an article that may help](http://tech.pro/tutorial/705/javascript-tutorial-the-scroll-wheel). There's also [another stack overlflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527601/normalizing-mousewheel-speed-across-browsers) which may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to differentiate between separate continuous scroll and not consider the duration of the scroll you can `unbind` `mousewheel` and rebind after a delay. Expanding on @wrxsti solution, it would look like this:

```
var i = 0;
var u = 0;
var d = 0;
$(document).bind('mousewheel', updateValues)

function updateValues(e){
    i++;
    $('#all').text(i);
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        u++;
        $('#up').text(u);
    } else {
        d++;
        $('#down').text(d);
    }
    $(document).unbind('mousewheel');
   setTimeout(function(){$(document).bind('mousewheel', updateValues)}, 500);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6enbeq2/2/

Comment: Not working with kinetic scrolling (all Apple laptops trackpads and magic mouses).
You have to be very careful when trying to deal with the mouse wheel...

Answer (score 2):

Something to this effect might work for your purposes. Try binding the mousewheel.

```
var i = 0;
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(){
    i++;
    $('div').text(i);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6wefywh6/1/)

Additionally, if you wanted to take it a step further you could determine the scroll direction.

```
var i = 0;
var u = 0;
var d = 0;
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    i++;
    $('#all').text(i);
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        u++;
        $('#up').text(u);
    } else {
        d++;
        $('#down').text(d);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1k3zLdpu/2/)