# Smooth mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll, mousewheel

I use chrome and scrolling is fast but its dont smooth. Text jumps multiple times.
But on this site http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/ scroll works very smooth! And FAST!
http://bassta.bg/demos/smooth-page-scroll/ This scroll is smooth but very sloow and lagga (fast mount wheel dont change speed of scroll screen)
How this site have this smooth scroll? I cant find it(

Comment: It's up to the website and it's developer. Not to chrome's settings I believe

Comment: additionally on the second website you linked it's a demo of the available tutorial: http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/

Comment: Notice that if you use mouse scroll on the first page, instead of dragging the bar with a mouse, the effect is also smooth

Comment: possible duplicate of [Normalizing mousewheel speed across browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527601/normalizing-mousewheel-speed-across-browsers)

Comment: No. i need - how first site make this. Second site - example how i dont need - its a slow scroll in fast wheel movement.

Comment: I recently made a [very simple, responsive, cross browser smooth mouse wheel scroll](https://github.com/nickzuber/silk-scroll) if you want to check it out! I also had the problem that most scripts would scroll too slow, mine works well for me =)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 300;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry( its laggy. Try scroll fast fast more times and page slooow scroll. :(

Comment: change the time variable and try

Comment: you do not understand how to make the page scrolls slowly, if there is one turn roller and faster, if the user scrolls down the page quickly. How do I make it faster and smoother been?

Answer (score -1):

First make a link with #top link then try the following code
try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);//here you can specify your time for smooth operation
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: OP asked how to control the mouse scroll speed and not a scroll to top feature.

Comment: OP isn't asking how to smoothly scroll to a section of the screen, but how to smoothly scroll in general without any skipping around.