# How to do slow scrolling like these website are doing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, scroll

There are several websites where I see smooth slow scrolling. I have been looking for plugins for react or vue. I basically want to learn how to do it with vanilla Javascript. Also you can suggest plugins libraries and whatever you want. But I want to know how to do it in pure vanilla js. I want to learn to control scroll speed.

here are the websites:

1. https://nana-asia.com/
2. https://pelizzari.com/en
3. https://loerarchitecten.com/en/projects/republica-short-guy

you can tell me what these websites are using also tell me how to do it using pure js.

Comment: See this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011055/smooth-vertical-scrolling-on-mouse-wheel-in-vanilla-javascript

Comment: I was literaly looking for it for so long

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

- Catch the mousewheel and touch events and prevent their orignal behaviour.
- Detect direction and speed of touch events or scroll amount for mousewheel events
- Use the event values and map those to the desired scroll level
- Apply a CSS translate to your page content

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to scroll smoothly like the first like here is a good plugin 
https://jokertattoo.co.uk/js/SmoothScroll.js
You can mess around with these values till you get a result you want:

```
 frameRate        : 150, // [Hz]
    animationTime    : 2000, // [px]
    stepSize         : 150, // [px]
```

and here is a demo of it in action:
https://ui-unicorn.co.uk/my-cv/