# why is deltaY on `wheel` event different between mac and windows?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When I try to get the scroll speed of a user I get inconsistent results between mac and windows.

#### to reproduce

1. Open [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-delta-test-p4zxh?file=/src/styles.css)
2. With a mouse, scroll down 1 "tick" (use a mouse that doesn't have smooth scroll)

### problem

Using the exact same hardware (mouse / monitor) and browser (chrome):

- on Windows I get a value of **125**
- on Mac I get a value of around **12**

I need a way to know how fast the user scrolled that gives comparable results for all operating systems.

#### more context

- This is for a "infinite canvas" type application (like [tldraw](https://tldraw.com/)).
  I would like to "zoom out" when the user scrolls backwards and "zoom in" when the user scrolls in.
- I want to use the scroll speed (and not just the scroll direction) because otherwise it feels clunky
- I know that it's possible because [figma](https://figma.com/) can zoom in/out based on mouse wheel speed. Though they use webgl so not sure if they have access to properties that the normal wheel event doesn't have
- I can't simply check if deltaY is > 100 because on mac deltaY can get over 100 when the user scrolls fast
- I tried every solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527601/normalizing-mousewheel-speed-across-browsers?answertab=active#tab-top). None of them worked across mac/windows

Comment: any luck?  I have the same issue